# Как реализовать поиск по базе данных Sqlite в Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

Например, есть переменная в ней значения `'Борщ'` или `'Борщ по-польськи'` и мне нужно найти совпадение в таблице `Content`, а затем вернуть найденный результат.

в `'Content'` => `title` будут хранится такие данные:

```
 id |  title           | description |  img  |
----+------------------+-------------+-------+
  1 | Солодкий борщ    |    TEXT     | TEXT  |
----+------------------+-------------+-------+
  2 | Борщ по-польськи |    TEXT     | TEXT  |
----+------------------+-------------+-------+
  3 | Холодний борщ    |    TEXT     | TEXT  |
----+------------------+-------------+-------+
```

БД: SQLite3 , Python 3.5

#### Ошибка по установки библиотеки `APSW`

```
C:\Users\NameUser>pip install apsw
Collecting apsw
  Using cached apsw-3.9.2-r1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: apsw
  Running setup.py install for apsw ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\NameUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Temp\\pip-build-y1sxrjbt\\apsw\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Temp\pip-jg4_ur_s-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    c:\users\NameUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:285: UserWarning: Normalizing '3.9.2-r1' to '3.9.2.post1'
      normalized_version,
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    SQLite: Using amalgamation C:\Temp\pip-build-y1sxrjbt\apsw\sqlite3\sqlite3.c
    building 'apsw' extension
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\NameUser\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Temp\\pip-build-y1sxrjbt\\apsw\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Temp\pip-jg4_ur_s-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Temp\pip-build-y1sxrjbt\apsw\
```

Comment: Вам дали фактически правильный ответ. Для более точного ответа приведите больше информации: какую версию sqlite вы используете? С поддержкой ICU? Как именно вы работаете с БД из Питона? И, наконец, покажите ваши усилия: что вы уже сделали? Покажите ваш код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для поддержки поиска без учёта регистра с помощью `LIKE` для не-ascii текста, необходимо включить `icu` расширение. Тогда запрос `LIKE '%борщ%'` найдёт строки содержащие как «борщ» так и «Борщ».

Чтобы быстрее искать по целым словам, можно использовать `fts4` расширение: `MATCH 'борщ'`. Для поддержки Unicode casefolding, при создании виртуальной таблицы для fts можно также включить icu, например:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE soup USING fts4(title TEXT,tokenize=icu)
```

`MATCH 'Холодний борщ'` найдёт строки содержащие заданные слова в любом порядке, например также будет найден: «Борщ холодный».

---

Чтобы была возможность включить `icu` расширение, сборка sqlite должна поддерживать расширения вообще и скомпилирована с опциями специально для `icu` расширения в частности. Относительно простой способ получить sqlite сборку, в которой можно включить icu—это [использовать `apsw` модуль](http://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/). Наличие своей сборки не мешает использовать системную sqlite даже в том же процессе.

Вот полный пример кода, использующий apsw, чтобы найти не-ascii текст без учёта регистра в sqlite:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
import apsw

connection = apsw.Connection(":memory:")
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE soup USING fts4(title TEXT,tokenize=icu)')
with connection as db:
    db.cursor().executemany('insert into soup(title) values(?)',
                            [['Солодкий борщ'], ['Борщ по-польськи'],
                             ['по-польськи борщ'], ['Холодний борщ'], ['Солянка']])
# NOTE: no Борщ on sqlite3 but it is found with apsw with the enabled icu extension
# NOTE: 'like' works but it may be slow compared to the fts4 'match'
for title, in cur.execute('SELECT title FROM soup WHERE title LIKE ?', ['%бор%']):
    print(title)
print('*' * 60)
for title, in cur.execute('SELECT title FROM soup WHERE title MATCH ?', ['борщ']):
    print(title)
```

#### Результат

```
Солодкий борщ
Борщ по-польськи
по-польськи борщ
Холодний борщ
************************************************************
Солодкий борщ
Борщ по-польськи
по-польськи борщ
Холодний борщ
```

Чтобы установить [`apsw`-версию из репозитория](https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw) на Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libicu-dev icu-devtools # icu-config
$ git clone https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw.git
$ cd apsw
# NOTE: use virtualenv, to isolate the installation
$ python setup.py fetch --all build --enable-all-extensions install
$ python setup.py test
```

[Есть готовые сборки под разные платформы, которые поддерживают некоторые расширения](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/download.html).

Comment: мой pyCharm не видит библиотеку `apsw`
по попытке установить через `pip` видает ошибку

Comment: @Surfer ваше IDE тут не причём. Мне следовало бы явно упомянуть, что apsw не совместим с pip как это явно сказано в последней  ссылке в ответе. Также видно, что `pip` не использовался при установке в командах, явно приведённых в ответе. Как установить `apsw` на Windows это отдельный вопрос—не следует его смешивать с текущим. Начните со скачивания бинарных установщиков (следуйте по последней ссылке в ответе), если не получится, задайте отдельный вопрос по установке (не забудьте упомянуть какую конфигурацию пытаетесь поставить—какие расширения вам нужны).

Comment: ошибка при инсталляции на windows,
брал отсюда: https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/download.html

---------------------------
Cannot install
---------------------------
Python version 3.5 required, which was not found in the registry.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: почему все так трудно, попроще никак нельзя?

Comment: да, установка `apsw` нестандартная. Официальная причина: автор говорит, что для установки необходимо опции задавать (например, для fetch, build команд), а `pip` только `--install-option` и общие опции может передавать в `setup.py`. Опции по умолчанию по-видимому религия не позволяет выбрать. Предполагая, что у вас всё-таки Python 3.5 установлен стандартным образом, то сообщение об ошибке интересное и достойно своего вопроса. Если официальные бинарники не работают, также пробуйте: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#apsw

Comment: и как мне этот файл   `apsw-3.12.2.post1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`    установить ?

Comment: @Surfer попробуйте отдельный вопрос задать о том как `*.whl` в контексте Питона устанавливать. Ответ простой. Так вы себе и другим с тем же вопросом  поможете

Comment: если я на Виндовсе соберу, будет ли она потом работать на других ОС?

Comment: @Surfer в ответе явно команды для Ubuntu приведены. То есть да код и на других системах может работать.

Comment: ошибка
`cur.execute('CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE soup USING fts4(title TEXT,tokenize=icu)')
  File "d:\build\apsw\apsw-3.12.2-r1\src\cursor.c", line 236, in resetcursor
apsw.SQLError: SQLError: unknown tokenizer: icu`

Comment: @Surfer это значит, что у вас версия без icu расширения. По-видимому, если хотите чтобы "борщ" находил также "Борщ", то нужно самостоятельно собрать пакет. Команда для сборки на Windows доступна в последней ссылке в ответе (`python setup.py fetch ... install ...`). У вас должен быть компилятор установлен, который может С расширения для питона собирать. Учитывая у вас были сложности просто закачать файл с интернета, установка компилятора может быть на данном этапе слишком сложной задачей.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title FROM Content WHERE title LIKE '%Борщ%'
```

Запросы лучше делать именно в sql до готового варианта.
Так как они будут выполнять быстрее, чем скажем если из sql промежуточный вариант выдернуть и его обрабатывать.

Comment: И чем ваш ответ отличается от ответа Batanichek?

Comment: Советом использования.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ещё регистром отличается. Как следует из [моего ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521462/23044), по умолчанию `'%Борщ%'` и `'%борщ%'` могут к разным результатам вести.

Comment: Кстати да, регистрозависимые

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  title 
from content 
 where lower(title) like lower('%Борщ%')
```

Comment: Без поддержки ICU это не работает.

Answer (score -1):

думаю все что нужно это `like`

наподобие

```
select 
title 
from Content 
where title like '%борщ%'
```

Comment: Думаю, "Борщ" с большой буквы не найдёт. Но это проблема sqlite.