# Не работает запрос в sqlite: LIKE '%?%'—ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Таблица `foods` содержит поле `food_names`, в котором через пробелы перечислены синонимы названия продукта, например: `beer пиво пивко пивасик`, причем названий-синонимов может быть от одного и более.

Я хочу выбрать  все строки таблицы, поля `food_names` которых содержат по крайней мере одно слово, использумое в запросе.
Т.е. я хочу сделать запрос, например,

```
SELECT * FROM foods WHERE food_names LIKE '%пиво%'
```

Получается:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect("foods.db")
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> c.execute("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE food_names LIKE '%?%'", ("пиво",))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE food_names LIKE '%?%'", ("пиво",))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.
>>>
```

Что надо исправить?

Comment: В сторону: почитайте о [нормализации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). Можно синонимы в отдельной таблице хранить (каждая строчка пара синонимов—пара id из food таблицы), если динамически списки синонимов могут создаваться. Можно [использовать ORM, чтобы автоматически таблицы сгенерировать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11914666/4279). 2- можно [fts4 расширение использовать, чтобы по словам искать в SQLite](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520072/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работать будет вариант:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE food_names LIKE ?", ("%пиво%",))
```

Если знак вопроса ? в тексте запроса обернут кавычками (как в '%?%'), парсер распознает его как именно знак вопроса как таковой, как букву, но не как точку подстановки параметра.