# Python сортировка списков в списке

Tags: python

имеется список, внутри которых находятся списки. Нужно, чтобы списки внутри списка располагались например по алфавиту.

Некоторые внутренние списки имеют в себе значения None.
Это нужно для того, чтобы удалить дубликаты.
Количество списков больше 32000, поэтому проходить по каждому из них и сравнивать с другими занимает большое количество времени.
Поэтому и нужна сортировка. Также стоит отметить, что количество дубликатов в списках не превышает 1, поэтому если отсортировать списки, список нужно сравнивать с соседним, а не со всеми остальными.
Пробовал метод `.sort`, но он ругается, что есть значения NoneType

Пример строк:

```
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Даттах']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Зандак']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Гиляны']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Байтарки']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Саясан']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Аллерой']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Турты-Хутор']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Большие-Шуани']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Гордали']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Центорой']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Энгеной']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Беной']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Гендерген']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Беной-Ведено']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Симсир']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', None]
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Шовхал-Берды']
['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Даттах']
```

Comment: А вы эти данные случайно не из БД получаете? Если да, то отсортируйте на стороне базы данных

Comment: `sorted(filter(lambda x: x is not None, ['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', 'Зандак']))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные читаются из БД, то наиболее эффективно будет отсортировать их прямо в базе данных:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
ORDER BY column_name  /*  сортировка */
```

если такой возможности нет, то можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
In [144]: import pandas as pd

In [145]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [146]: df
Out[146]:
                       0     1                   2                3             4
0   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Даттах
1   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Зандак
2   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Гиляны
3   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский      Байтарки
4   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Саясан
5   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский       Аллерой
6   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский   Турты-Хутор
..                   ...   ...                 ...              ...           ...
11  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский         Беной
12  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский     Гендерген
13  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский  Беной-Ведено
14  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Симсир
15  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский          None
16  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский  Шовхал-Берды
17  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Даттах

[18 rows x 5 columns]

In [147]: df.sort_values(4)
Out[147]:
                       0     1                   2                3              4
5   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Аллерой
3   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский       Байтарки
11  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский          Беной
13  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский   Беной-Ведено
7   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский  Большие-Шуани
12  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский      Гендерген
2   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский         Гиляны
..                   ...   ...                 ...              ...            ...
4   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский         Саясан
14  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский         Симсир
6   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский    Турты-Хутор
9   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский       Центорой
16  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский   Шовхал-Берды
10  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Энгеной
15  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский           None

[18 rows x 5 columns]

In [148]: res = df.sort_values(4).values.tolist()
```

результат:

```
In [150]: res
Out[150]:
[['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Аллерой'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Байтарки'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Беной'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Беной-Ведено'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Большие-Шуани'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Гендерген'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Гиляны'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Гордали'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Даттах'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Даттах'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Зандак'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Саясан'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Симсир'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Турты-Хутор'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Центорой'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Шовхал-Берды'],
 ['Чеченская Республика',
  None,
  'Гудермесский район',
  'Ножай-Юртовский',
  'Энгеной'],
 ['Чеченская Республика', None, 'Гудермесский район', 'Ножай-Юртовский', None]]
```

---

чтобы отсортировать DataFrame по всем столбцам:

```
In [151]: df.sort_values(df.columns.tolist())
Out[151]:
                       0     1                   2                3              4
5   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Аллерой
3   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский       Байтарки
11  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский          Беной
13  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский   Беной-Ведено
7   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский  Большие-Шуани
12  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский      Гендерген
2   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский         Гиляны
..                   ...   ...                 ...              ...            ...
4   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский         Саясан
14  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский         Симсир
6   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский    Турты-Хутор
9   Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский       Центорой
16  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский   Шовхал-Берды
10  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский        Энгеной
15  Чеченская Республика  None  Гудермесский район  Ножай-Юртовский           None

[18 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Данные только подготавливаются для добавления в бд. Получается у вас только сортирует только по 4 столбцу? А как отсортировать, одновременно по всем?

Comment: @danilshik, __одновременно__ - никак, а если последовательно, т.е. сначала, по 1-му, потом по 2-му, и т.д. (аналог в SQL: `ORDER BY col1, col2, col3, col4, ...`) то `df.sort_values([0,1,2,3,4])`

Comment: для сортировки без учёта регистра  данных в БД, может специальная поддержка со стороны базы данных потребоваться. Пример для [поиска без учёта регистра не ascii текста в sqlite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520072/23044)

Comment: для полноты (для будущих посетителей из гугла, привлечённых заголовком вопроса) пример сортировки вложенных список без pandas, sql в Питоне можно показать: `data.sort(key=key)` где для сравнения можно ключ типа: [`icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('ru')).getSortKey`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446833/23044)

Comment: @jfs, можете показать в собственном ответе - у посетителей будет возможность выбрать тот ответ, который им больше подходит...

Comment: лучше если на самом верху принятого ответа будет: `data.sort()` (весь код для однотипных данных), чтобы люди не думали, что сложно сортировку использовать, что нужно сторонние библиотеки, базы данных привлекать для сортировки вложенных списков в Питоне (остальное детали).